# Calling multiple PHP methods simultaneously?

Tags: php, multithreading

I have a PHP class that has several methods that make various API calls. I'd like to create one method that can call these various methods at the same time in order to save time. My idea was to somehow to use multithreaded cURL, but I'm not sure if that's the right approach.

Is there a way I can make several methods run at the same time?

NOTE: I don't want to have to rely on various extensions, such as `pthreads`, if possible. I fear that's going to be a nightmare trying to setup on my host. I do not necessarily need "true" multithreading -- just something faster than sequentially calling the methods.

Comment: You are going to require multi-threading one way or another

Comment: OK - what's the easiest way to implement this?

Comment: The only alternative to threads is to spawn several programs.

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to do. BTW - Spawning processes is quite expensive - what are those methods doing?

Comment: The methods are basically doing an API call -- nothing too fancy. Just some simple "get" functions.

Comment: And this is too slow?!

Comment: Not very slow. But I do need to make about 5 calls -- and each call takes almost a second.

Comment: fiddling with multi-threading in PHP is always a bad thing to do - its much better to let your server execute a long-running process and call that script on the client via asynchronous AJAX-requests and show loading-GIFs in the meanwhile. PHP wasnt made for these things ... if you want real multithreading you will need to choose another language, scripting languages like PHP are very limited.

Answer (score 0):

I see two options.

First is to use forking.

The other is to separate those api calls somehow, and call the approptiate php scripts from console. For that purpouse you have shell_exec function

Comment: Can I call that class from a separate file via multi-threaded curl? I'm just not sure how I can tell that class which method I want it to execute.

Comment: If you're going to call it with shell_exec, you can pass command line arguments, like this: "php myscript.php arg1 arg2". You can get those arguments with $argv variable in your script, and decide what to execute based on that input

Comment: Which method in myscript.php would receive arg1 and arg2?

Comment: Here's an example: https://gist.github.com/shonezlo/86e7f9104919584ea849

If you call it like this: "php cli-example.php one" , it will call api function one. You need to write some logic to handle arguments

Answer (score 0):

Curl multi exec is what you need 
Its weird to use though so would recommend using a class such as

https://github.com/petewarden/ParallelCurl

Comment: how do I call the class from a separate file and specifically call a certain method in that class? I'm not in a framework or anything, so no routing to access methods, etc.

Comment: What ever is calling the api methods that's what should he using multi curl